# playframework app cannot connect to database "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (use password: YES)"

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have the correct username and password and it is correctly configured in the `application.conf`. I know this because I haven't changed the `application.conf` and it worked a couple of hours ago. What *has* changed is that I upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS (took several steps through the other LTS releases). This also upgraded MySQL from 5.5.43 to 8.0.26. I did not initially upgrade the mysql-connector, but after my app failed to connect to the database, I tried upgrading the connector from 5.1.18 to 8.0.26.

I can log in to MySQL directly from the command line with `mysql` and the same username and password from `application.conf`, so I know the username and password still work.

Here's the exception I get from my Play Framework app:

```
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver has automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:247)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.onStart(DB.scala:238)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
    at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:55)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:253)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:289)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:284)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:284)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:363)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:240)
    ... 18 more
```

And here's the successful login from the command line:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 31
Server version: 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

`application.conf` has the following lines:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase"
db.default.user=root
db.default.pass="password"
```

I have Play Framework 2.3.9 and Java 1.8.0_51 (both unchanged during the upgrade).

Comment: I dropped and (re-)created the root user using this approach https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131286/problem-in-accessing-to-mysql and this did _not_ work. I then tried using the admin user that I just created and that user _did_ work! So something is special about the root user that was not special before. This seems to be a MySQL thing.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>remove quotes from password in config</strike> 
I checked the spec, you're right quotes dont matter.

Comment: Doesn't work. The config should permit quotes or no quotes on the right hand side, but I did try it without quotes to be sure.

Comment: Remember that I haven't changed my config, play version (or installation), and this worked a couple hours ago! What has changed is the operating system, MySQL, and any number of underlying system libraries.

Comment: The JVM is also the same... I'll add the version to my OP.

Comment: Did you switch drivers, not just up the versions per the message: The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, too. I get the same exact exception.

Comment: This is incredibly puzzling!! Just for fun, I plugged in the wrong hostname, wrong port, commented out the password... in all cases I got appropriate error messages. So I know everything is making it through, including the password. I even retyped the password, twice, very carefully.

Comment: I wasn't using play but had an issue w/ scala (and other java apps) on ubuntu after an upgrade. I reinstalled mysql. No idea what's going on here.

Comment: And that worked?

Comment: Yeah, but it was on ubuntu 17, and was easy to do since it was a blank dev install of mysql. I'll delete my answer since i've contributed nothing here. Happy hunting.

Comment: I just removed and installed mysql. It didn't help. I think you may leave your answer.

Comment: It helps for people to see all that was tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237680/discussion-between-zmf-and-jason).